# Meteor: Create a loading widget using ReactiveVar for subscribing to users collection

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, loading, reactive-programming

I had a loading function for my home template which worked nicely for the subscription of the users collection.  Unfortunately with this, the loading took up the whole page and I would like to display some general information so long while I wait for the users to load.

I've implemented this in my create account function with my sign up template using ReactiveVar and that worked nicely.

This is how it was done there:

```
Template.signup.onCreated(function() {
  Template.instance().isLoading = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.signup.helpers({
  isLoading() {
    return Template.instance().isLoading.get();
  }
});

Template.signup.events({
  'submit #signup-form': function(event, template) {
    // Not important stuff here
    template.isLoading.set(true);
    Accounts.createUser({
      // More not important stuff here
    }, function(err) {
      // Even more not important stuff here
      template.isLoading.set(false);
    })
  }
});
```

Then in the template I have this:

```
<template name="signup>
  {{#unless isLoading}}
    <!-- Stuff -->
  {{else}}
    <!-- More Stuff -->
    {{> loading}}
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

This works really well but I want to do the same sort of thing for my home page where I subscribe to users.  Is there a way to do something similar?  I've set up the home template calls and stuff.  But I don't know how to do the template events for loading user data.

This is what I have basically:

```
Template.home.onCreated(function() {
  Template.instance().isLoading = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.home.helpers({
  user: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({});
  },
  isLoading() {
    return Template.instance().isLoading.get();
  }
});

Template.home.events({
  //What do I do here????
});
```

I appreciate any help I can get :)

Edit:  Here's my Meteor publish code:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {username: 1, emails: 1, profile: 1}});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the Blaze helper Template.subscriptionsReady:

```
<template name="home">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        <!-- Your template code -->
    {{else}}
        <!-- Your loading code -->
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Here is a link to relevant documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe

Comment: The doesn't seem to run the code that runs in the else statement :/

Comment: Hmm are you specifically trying to get all users' info on home or just the currently logged in user?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get every user that exists.

Comment: Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {username: 1, emails: 1, profile: 1}});
  });

And now I've just realized I left out the roles field in my publish code.  Thanks for helping me see what's wrong.  I'll update my question  with that code and you can answer what to do from there.

Comment: It worked, editing your answer to include a note of what fixed it